# alignment html elements more a math thing than anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I have a little problem here.. any hints how to solve this is appreciated :)
I think this is a math problem but...

I have a draggable element on a 1920 canvas (but may be any size depending on user browser window size..
Supose that i have a button ( width:200px ), and another elements for instance some text ( width: 500px )

In my "viewport" (1920) i drag this 2 elements to left position: 200px
and save..

then i go to another browser window (preview) and i change my window to 1400px

what i want is that those 2 elements to get aligned in my new window size (1400). A porportional left position based on my new viewport.
I draw at 1920, and i want to render in 1400..

What is hapening is that because my 2 elements have different widths they get porportional disaligned on my new "resolution".

if the elements are rendered in the same window size ( build at 1920 and render ate 1920 ) they get correctly aligned.
If diff browser windows they get disaligned.

In attach 2 images:
( 1º - wireframe of desired final output ) 
( 2º - real prints of what is happening )

algo.. this "formula" also need to work/align for instance center/center of the viewport width ( being that 1920, 1400, etc )

Best regards and thank you.[image]

Comment: You can use `percentage` instead of `pixel`.

Comment: Basically, you need a reference point in the elements and scale this. If this is the left edge, then all elements should align perfectly after scaling (because the left edges have the same distance from the left viewport border).